# Duda sobre archivos -shm y -wal al crear base de datos

Tags: android, base-de-datos

tengo una duda con unos archivos que se crean en el emulador al crear la base de datos SQLite:

Tengo una base de datos llamada "agenda", la cual guardo desde "...data\com.example.agenda\agenda.db" para verla fuera de android con un programa llamado "DB Browser for SQLite", pero me di cuenta que en algún momento se crearon otros dos archivos mas: "agenda-shm" y "agenda-wal" y desde entonces tengo problemas con la base de datos, no se si se deba a esto o no pero quiero descartar que lo sea.

Espero alguien sepa orientarme que significan esos archivos que antes no me aparecían.

Muchas gracias y saludos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo este enlace a la misma pregunta (en inglés), la respuesta marcada lo explica muy bien.

[Archivos -shm y -wal en SQLite (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928294/shm-and-wal-files-in-sqlite-db)

Te hago un resumen:

- Ese `agenda-smh` contiene un índice que apunta a `agenda-wal`, optimiza la lectura del fichero `wal`. Si borras este índice, se volverá a generar con cada acceso a la base de datos.
- Ese `agenda-wal` será borrado automáticamente al cerrar la última conexión con tu base de datos. No debes preocuparte de esos ficheros.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre debes Guardar (Save as) los tres archivos. Luego abre tu DB en el "DB Browser for SQLite". Cuando cierres tu base de datos desde el Browser desapareceran los otros dos archivos guardados y solo quedara tu DB.